# looping through 2 columns individually and completely

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

[Related question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1191457/excel-vba-copy-rows-if-data-match-with-values-in-column-in-another-sheet?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have 2 columns of different length.

In the below Do While loop,

```
Do While main.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" Or main.Offset(i, 1).Value <> ""
```

using OR, it generates tons of irrelevant data (like not matching name/tag in sheet2) so I change to AND, it works perfectly Only if both columns end at the same row. (although there are duplicates, but they wasn't my main concern now)

```
Do While main.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" And main.Offset(i, 1).Value <> ""
```

But using the logical operator 'And', it stops halfway ( if one of the column is shorter than the other.
Can any expert shed some light on how to get the data even when one column is shorter than another?

I tried to add parenthesis between both statements, put one of the column in another sheet, or create a nested do while loop, the data still remain the same.
I also tried the below code, but it gives all irrelevant data like "Ken, summer,wendy" in sheet2.

```
Do While (main.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" And main.Offset(i, 1).Value <> "") Or (main.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" And main.Offset(i, 1).Value = "")
```

so I was wondering what I could use to replace the And operator and gives me correct results?

[image: ah]Here is Xsheet, Sheet1, Sheet2.
I am not able to post more than 2 pictures, so I put them all in One.
As above picture shown, Belle is in the Xsheet and also an active case.
So 3355 is supposed to be in Sheet2. Another defect where there is duplicates of 4987.

*[image: Added latest screenshot]

I am new to programming, I apologize if I am making any unnecessary mistake.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: As mentioned by @ejbytes, it is difficult to understand, what you want. For me, it seems your criterias in natural speech and your code follow **not** the same logic. Please can you explain what you want to do with your data and your criterias? I presume you need some additional criterias in your loop or if-clauses.

Comment: What is your actual goal here? You could nest the loops but the outer would terminate early. So you would probably have to check the length beforehand and make a decision on how to proceed based on that information.

Comment: Hi @IQV, apologize for not able to explain myself well. No excuse but I am not a native english speaker, still learning. As ejbytes mentioned, "If the Name or the Description on the Master List (Xsheet) is found in the Data Sheet (Sheet1) and it is also Active, then copy it to a new sheet", that is what i am trying to get. but now that I come across with bigger data and two columns (Name and Desciption) of different length, I have the problem as mentioned in the question. +screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think, your do-while-loop doesn't fit your needs - no matter if with `OR` or `AND`. As I understand, you can process the two columns in XSheet one after another. For me it seems, the data in columns A and B are independently.

So first you check if the names are in column E of Sheet1, then copy data to Sheet2. After that you check if the descriptions are in column F of Sheet1 and then copy the data.

But before inserting the data found in column "description" you have to check, if you copied these row already. So if you got a hit in desc, you take the "code" of column A and check if it is already in Sheet2. If it is so, you do nothing, otherwise you copy the data.

And of course you always have to check, if your hit is "active".

**EDIT:** The do-while-loop itself is correct. But the condition with `AND` or `OR` is not necessary. So the checks mentioned above are both

```
Do While main.Offset(i, 0).Value <> ""
```

for colunm D resp. column E.

Comment: Hi @IQV, thanks. yes, that's what i want to do and both columns are independent. So I'm just going to search for method to check the name column first and then the folllowing. May I know if the do-while loop doesn't fit, what's the other option that could meet my needs?

Comment: Edited answer to clarify.

Comment: Hi @IQV, I did tried on this line before. It's not working, I have uploaded the output screenshot. Ya, so the closest i could get is with the And. Strange, I thought stating with another condition could solve. 
Do While (main.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" And main.Offset(i, 1).Value <> "") Or (main.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" And main.Offset(i, 1).Value = ""). but no luck